# Can I show committer's email in bash prompt?

Tags: git

This is my actual prompt:

```
username@ current-folder (current-branch) $
```

Could I change username with committer's username? I just want to be sure about the committer data. This because I've different account, a global .gitconfig and many local ./git/config files.

Sometimes I've been committed with wrong email. Is it possible to show committer's email in prompt so then I'll never commit with wrong data?

Comment: Which shell are you using? Please tag accordingly.

Comment: I guess this can be done by using output of `git config user.email` in `$PS1`. Can we know the shell you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fetch the current committer email with

```
git config user.email
```

So just change your prompt to say something like

```sh
PS1='$(git config user.email)@ \w$(__git_ps1)\$ '
#    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```